# Can we use a lower version of Delphi (Delphi xe5) to edit a project file from the higher version (Delphi xe6)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

Every time I run the .dproj file in xe5, I get an error "Exception EReadError in module StartCoatPro.exe at 000C0304. Error reading LineSeries1.Legend.Visible: Property Legend.Visible does not exist."

I tried looking for the Legend.Visible property under LineSeries1 in the .dfm file but I couldn't find it. Then I also tried to put a line, Legend.Visible = True, but doesn't seem to work too. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say without more background. You should provide a [mcve]. And details of which TChart version you are using, if not the one supplied with Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Project files are version-specific.  You cannot edit an XE6 project in the XE5 IDE and vice versa, for instance.

But what you are experiencing is not a project problem, it is a DFM problem.  You have an XE6 DFM that contains a value for a property that apparently does not exist in XE5.  Do not try to edit DFM files across version boundaries, either.  Newer versions tend to store new properties that cause errors in earlier versions.

Cross-version project management is tricky.  Best not to share version-specific files at all, unless you use third-party tools to help you.  For instance, there are tools available that manipulate DFMs to strip out newer properties when downgrading to an older IDE.